# Add rows in datagridview in vb.net from SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am facing a problem here, the below code have no error, but I would like to fetch data from SQL Server and add rows in datagridview rather than show in the textbox and then add to datagridview.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        'searchcproduct
        con = connection()

        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = " select * from product  where plucode='" & TextBox2.Text & "' or barcode='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
        Dim dbreader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dbreader.HasRows = False Then
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Focus()
            itemnotfound.Show()
            PlayBackgroundSoundFile1()
        ElseIf dbreader.HasRows = True Then
            While dbreader.Read()
                TextBox4.Text = dbreader.Item("plu_description")
                TextBox5.Text = dbreader.Item("unitprice")
                TextBox7.Text = dbreader.Item("plu_qty")
                TextBox8.Focus()
            End While

        End If
    End If
    'TextBox2.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub Button20_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button20.Click
    Dim rowNumber As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    Try
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rowNumber).Cells(0).Value = Me.TextBox2.Text ' i want to display sql rather than textbox
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rowNumber).Cells(1).Value = Me.TextBox4.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rowNumber).Cells(2).Value = Me.TextBox5.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rowNumber).Cells(3).Value = Me.TextBox8.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rowNumber).Cells(4).Value = Val(Me.TextBox5.Text) * Val(Me.TextBox8.Text)
        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Me.Label2.Text = FormatNumber(totalsales(), 2).ToString()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "check")
    End Try
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    TextBox5.Text = ""
    TextBox8.Text = ""
    TextBox7.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure that you are closing your data readers and connections.

Comment: You really should be using parameters ...

Answer (score -1):

After calling `ExecuteReader`, create a `DataTable` and call its `Load` method, passing your data reader.  You can then assign that `DataTable` to the `DataSource` property of grid to display all the data, e.g.

```
Dim myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
Dim myDataTable As New DataTable

myDataTable.Load(myDataReader)
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable
```

Comment: hi jmcilhinney, i have tried but i receive an error invalid attempt to call metadata when reader is closed.

Comment: Then you must have closed the data reader before reading the data, which what `DataTable.Load` does.